# How do i convert my adjacency matrix to a distance matrix which is represented as an array type numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy

I have to use it without any Networkx functions except for the function adjacency_matrix.

I know how to get to the distance matrix but I am having trouble converting  it into an np.ndarray so I can access the elements.

I have got this after drawing my graph

```
G_A=np.array((nx.adjacency_matrix(G)))
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: the function `G_A.todense()` converts it to a ndarray

Comment: thanks but where does .todense come from?

Comment: As always: from the [docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix.html)

Comment: Could you also do .toarray?

Comment: Yeah that would be the same. Actually technically todense returns a matrix object and toarray returns a ndarray.

Comment: yep ive got it thanks for your help.